# Logrotate from an archive

Tags: logrotate

Can I configure `logrotate` to take the files to rotate from a single file?

INSTEAD OF

```
/var/log/prueba.log /var/log/prueba.test {
daily
rotate 30
missingok
notifempty
compress
delaycompress
}
```

This Part mentioned above ... from an archive for example

logrotate.example

Was I'm clear ?

Comment: To me no, you're not realy clear. Can you detail a bit more

Comment: the process is run from a configuration file ... right? well ... I want to know if you can create a file with each line of log to rotate ... I was clear?

Comment: Your question is not clear @cuetecuete, logrotate uses `/etc/logrotate.conf `as a main configuration file, this later points `/etc/logrotate.d/` which contains the log rotate configurations for different applications, so what is that you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I mean ... if instead of using the configuration file of the process, I can create a single file that contains all the lines to rotate ... now if I was clear?

Comment: So what you want to do is: overriding logrotate main configuration file, with yours ?

Comment: Yes !!! exactly !!

Comment: Can someone responds to my question ?